# IOS home screen icons: where put and what size?

Tags: ios

I've read several articles about customizing the home screen icon used by IOS (and some Android) phones/tablets for the "add to homescreen" option. I'm seeing different recommendations re: sizes of the pngs, number of pngs, and am not clear where I should upload it/them.

Here's a sample of articles; some WP specific, some not:
http://www.bryanhauer.com/2012/06/25/how-to-easily-create-iphone-ipad-home-screen-retina-icons-for-your-website/

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/quick-tip-custom-ios-home-screen-icons-for-your-website/

http://wpdaily.co/icon-ios-homescreen/

I like the idea of using one "large" icon and having the devices scale it, but does that work? If so, does it really need to be 512 x 512? That seems pretty big and large pngs are large files.

And where do I place the pngs? In the theme root? In the media library? In the images folder in the theme root?

Do I need to add anything to the code like <**img src="/**images/apple-touch-icon.png">

Has anyone done this for a Wordpress theme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the images needed to be in the directory where the "core" wp folders are, ie. the public_html, or in whatever sub-directory that contains the wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content, etc. I had been placing them in the theme root and nothing was happening. Moved them to the public_html and they started showing up!

In this case I was following the directions in the second article listed above: Quick Tip: Custom IOS Homescreen icons...